# C++-cli mixed types are not supported

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

I am trying to use cli/c++ system/multithreading for a opencv detection software I have. I have got several haarcascades which I want to use them in several threads in order to run simultaneously. I am trying to following the instructions from [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx). I have noticed that when I create ref class I cant defined as a class member opencv objects. For example when I am trying to define  private variables for my ref class Detection:

```
private:
   Mat *image;
   CascadeClassifier *cascade;
   double scale;
   int neighbors;   
public:
   Detection(cv::Mat &img, cv::CascadeClassifier  &cas, double sc, int neigh)
  {
      image = new cv::Mat(img);
      cascade = new cv::CascadeClassifier(cas);
      scale = sc;
      neighbors = neigh;    
  }
  void detect_faces(){

    Mat gray_image;
    cv::cvtColor((*image), gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::equalizeHist(gray_image, gray_image);
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces1;
    (*cascade).detectMultiScale( gray_image, faces1, scale, neighbors, 0| CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(3, 3), Size(190,190));
    faces.insert(faces.end(), faces1.begin(), faces1.end());
}
```

Main function:

```
 int main()
 {
   Mat image = imread(...);
   cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade1;
   face_cascade1.load("cascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml");   
   Detection^ obj1 = gcnew Detection(image, face_cascade1, 1.01,5);
   ThreadStart^ myThreadDelegate1 = gcnew ThreadStart(obj1,  &Detection::detect_faces );
   Thread^ Thread1 = gcnew Thread( myThreadDelegate1 );

   Thread1->start();
   ...//the rest threads
  }
```

This code it seems to work. However as Berak mention I shouldnt make copy of cascadeClassifier. Is there something else I could do? Is there an issue of loosing time with that implementation? Moreover is there a chance to move detectMultiScale in main function?

Comment: that's only the top of the iceberg. honestly, managed c++ and opencv do not go well together. if you want a class member, you'd have to use `CascadeClassifier* cascade` ( a pointer, new and delete.. ). also, know, that those CascadeClassifiers are *not* thread-safe. (inner state does not allow one cascade to be shared between several threads). please re-think your design. do you *really* need managed c++ ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. What I want is to have 7 different cascades running simultaneously. I want to run every new thread with different cascade.

Comment: well, one per thread would be ok ( once you get the pointers right...)

Comment: ah, also, you can't pass a copy like `void foo(CascadeClassifier cas)`, that will have to be a reference or pointer, like `Detection(cv::CascadeClassifier &cas, ...)`

Comment: I did something that worked. However I am not so sure about what I did and why it works.

Comment: How can I check if indeed all my threads working simultaneously?

Comment: YOU CAN NOT COPY A CASCADECLASSIFIER. was that loud enough ? `cascade = new cv::CascadeClassifier(cas);` <- this is still a copy, and will blow up at runtime.

Comment: Any alternatives? By the way it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

C++/CLI ref classes can only hold .Net objects or primitive types as members.
If you want to have a C++ member, you'll have to hold a pointer to it. (Which can be compiled to an integer type big enough to hold the pointer).

Now if you want to check if the threads are running concurrently, you can do 2 things:

1. Pause the program, and look at the threads window. **(Debug -> Windows -> Threads)**
   Here you can see all the working threads, but you might be unlucky and "miss" the timing that shows both threads working.
2. Add a long `sleep()` in each thread. just before starting its work. Then Pause the program like in (1) and if you see the threads waiting on the `sleep()` then it means they're working concurrently.

Comment: I have checked and threads running simultaneously. However I am using the code in Edit2. Berak suggests not to copy cascade classifier cascade = new cv::CascadeClassifier(cas);. However this implementation works. What could possible change here?